# React Query call query from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-query

So I have my components like this:

```
const A = ({ id }) => {
  const query = useMyQuery(id);

  return <B data={query.data} query={query} />
}

const B = ({ data, query }) => {
   return data.map(i => (<C item={i} query={query} />));
}

const C = ({ item, query }) => {
  return (
    <> 
      <SomeOther />
      <D query={query} />
    </>
  );
}

const D = ({ query }) => {
  const someAction = async () => {
     await doSmth();
     query.refetch();
  }

  return <button onClick={someAction}>Smth</button>;
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing the query 3 components down just to refetch. Is there a better way to do this without having to use context? I mean some integrated React Query solution?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using context? Its made for dealing with prop drilling

Comment: I just want to know if maybe there's an integrated solution since React Query is already using a provider, if not I will use context :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `queryClient.refetchQueries(key)` to refetch - it doesn't have to be the function retuned from useQuery.

Comment: I'm trying to refetch some queries, `queryClient.refetchQueries(['getActiveOrders']);` but it's not working for some reason